# Solving equation involving trigonometric functions with two variables

Tags: trigonometry

> Suppose $\alpha, \beta$ $ \epsilon $ $ (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$. If $ \tan{\beta}=\frac{\cot{\alpha}-1}{\cot{\alpha}+1}, $ find $ \alpha+\beta $.

Regarding the question above, how would one be able to simplify it so that the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ may be found?

I imagine there's a way to simplify it enough to be able to just eyeball the values, but still I might be wrong.

I would appreciate a solution to the problem above, and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The given equation is equivalent to $\tan \beta =\tan (\frac {\pi} 4 -\alpha)$.

To see this use the fact that $\tan (\frac {\pi} 4)=1$ and use  formula for $\tan (A-B)$ in terms of $\tan A$ and $\tan B$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, this isn't one of those problems where there's a specific trick that you have to know in order to crack it. One can proceed in a rather clever manner by exploiting the structure of the given equation and exploiting several identities known from previous studies. I will do this as follows:

$tan(\beta) = \frac{cot(\alpha) - 1}{cot(\alpha) + 1}$

First, let us multiply both sides by the denominator on the Right-Hand Side:

$tan(\beta)(cot(\alpha) + 1) = cot(\alpha) - 1$

Next, we multiply everything by $tan(\alpha)$. We get:

$tan(\beta)(1 + tan(\alpha)) = 1 - tan(\alpha)$

Simplifying, we get:

$tan(\beta) + tan(\alpha) = 1 - tan(\alpha)tan(\beta)$

We can do a division and we see that:

$\frac{tan(\beta) + tan(\alpha)}{1 - tan(\alpha)tan(\beta)} = 1$

If you noticed, the Left-Hand Side is just $tan(\alpha + \beta)$. Thus, we have:

$tan(\alpha + \beta) = 1$

Taking the inverse, we get:

$\alpha + \beta = \frac{\pi}{4}$

That's exactly what you wanted :)

Remember, be calm and approach the problem logically. Mathematics is more than just blind applications of formulas and blind computations of specific variables. You must be calm and prepared to use your creativity.